My Visual Studio seems to include files by default, my coworker's seems to exclude files by default
Baffled by a VS behavior difference between two machines/people here. When I open a project out of source control, I see this:

When they open the exact same byte identical sln/csproj on their machine, they see this:

Nothing is included, compilation fails with "does not contain a static Main" etc. The proj files are identical, cloned out of the same repo from the same commit
The csproj file looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>XXX_XxxxxXxxxxxxx</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.102.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Flurl" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

If I right click the Program.cs and choose "exclude" this is the diff on the repo:

If my coworker right clicks and Includes the ghosted files, this is the diff on the repo:

The best way I can describe it is mine seems to include any file unless I specifically exclude, whereas theirs will only include files in a project if they are specifically nominated for inclusion
Is there an "at VS level" settng that controls something like file inclusion, that could explain why two VS work so differently ? Both VS are latest 2022..
I can't see any "DefaultItemExcludes" (referred to here: How do I exclude files/folders from a .NET Core/Standard project?) mentioned in the project file; can default exclusions be set elsewhere in VS?

I grasp your current predicament, but your specific request remains unclear. Your inquiry pertains to MSBuild, and the csproj file you mentioned is indeed a component of MSBuild. MSBuild generates the individual files within the Visual Studio project. It's typical not to find DefaultItemExcludes; you must manually insert it into the csproj file by adhering to the tutorial you consulted. If you're still unable to resolve it and articulate your needs precisely, I may be able to assist you. Alternatively, you have the option to learn it on your own.
Additionally, the reason your colleague's project was excluded from the compilation is due to the project file being set to 'None' in the csproj file. In MSBuild, an item labeled as 'None' is a distinct category of project item that denotes files within a project. However, these files are neither compiled nor linked to the final output. Commonly, 'None' items include resource files, configuration files, script files, and similar files that support the project but are not required to be compiled into executable or library files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022

In this case my main question is "how can I make their visual studio work like mine?" because theirs works unintuitively right now. If they and I both clone the repo, we both open the sln on our respective machines, and they see all files included by default. I'm struggling to understand why, from a completely fresh (deleted the old folder) clone from the same commit in the same repo,then we both open the byte identical SLN,why the two VS would be different-how come theirs excludes all the files by default and mine includes? Are you saying some setting in VS dictates whether csproj Build=none?

I dont know why these  csproj file so diffrernt, but if you want to make their visual studio work like yours, just right click the project in solution explorer, chose "unload project",then right click the project and chose "edit project file".  just make their project file same like yours.

bad thing is you need do this every time. and there are many possible reason for your case.
try open other project, try reinstall vs to narrow the question.
